# Is the "naive" full level $N$ moduli problem on elliptic curves $\Gamma(N)$ étale over $\mathbf{(Ell)}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Following the notations and notions developped in Katz and Mazur's book "The arithmetic moduli of elliptic curves", we denote $\mathbf{(Ell)}$ the category whose objects are elliptic curves $E/S$ over variable base-schemes, and whose morphisms are Cartesian squares. A moduli problem is then simply a contravariant functor $\mathbf{(Ell)}\rightarrow \mathbf{(Set)}$. We say that a moduli problem $\mathcal{P}$ is étale if for any elliptic curve $E/S$, the functor $\mathbf{(Sch/S)}\rightarrow \mathbf{(Set)}$ sending an $S$-scheme $T$ to $\mathcal{P}(E_T/T)$ is representable by an étale $S$-scheme $\mathcal{P}_{E/S}$.

> Let $N\geq 1$ be an integer and let $\Gamma(N)$ denote the "naive" full level $N$ moduli problem, which takes an elliptic curve $E/S$ and sends it to the set of $S$-group-schemes isomorphisms $$\phi:\left(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}\right)_S^2\xrightarrow{\sim} E[N]$$ **Question**: Is $\Gamma(N)$ étale over $\mathbf{(Ell)}$?

Actually, I know that it is relatively representable (and even representable by an elliptic curve over a smooth affine curve over $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$, usually denoted $Y(N)$). If $E/S$ is any elliptic curve, then the $S$-scheme $\mathcal{P}_{E/S}$ associated to $\Gamma(N)$ is finite over $S$, and étale when $N$ is invertible on $S$. Is it also the case when $N$ is *not* invertible on $S$?

In other words, I know that it is étale when seen as a moduli problem on the category $\mathbf{(Ell_{\mathbb{Z}[1/N]})}$ of elliptic curves where $N$ is invertible, but is it also étale over the whole of $\mathbf{(Ell)}$?

NB: For context, this is claimed in Katz and Mazur's [book](http://math.bu.edu/people/jsweinst/AWS/Files/KatzMazurArithmeticModuli.pdf) on page 110 (page 61 in the pdf), and it is used on page 121 (page 66 in the pdf) when they describe its representing object $\mathbb{E}/Y(N)$ as a modular family.

I thank you very much for you clarifications.

Comment: @MarcPaul This comes from the fact that given an elliptic curve $E/S$ with a full level $N$ structure on it, $N$ must actually be invertible on $S$, right? I am also aware of this. However, I fail to see why, given an elliptic curve $E/S$ where $N$ is **not** invertible, then $\mathcal{P}_{E/S}\rightarrow S$ is étale. Even though there is no full level $N$ structure on $E/S$, $\mathcal{P}_{E/S}$ still exists. I think it is isomorphic as an $S$-scheme to $\operatorname{Isom}_{S\times Y(N)}(\operatorname{pr}_1^{\star}(E),\operatorname{pr}_2^{\star}(\mathbb{E}))$. But then...?

Comment: Let me give a slightly imprecise explanation of what's going on here. Consider $N=p$ a prime number. Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $k$. If one adds level $p$ structure over $k$ to $E$, then one "trivializes" the group scheme $E[p]$ over $k$. Now, the "reason" that this gives an etale cover of the moduli problem is partly because, when $p\neq 0$ in $k$, the order of $E[p]$ is independent of $E$ (and equals $p^2$). But, if $p=0$ in $k$, then this is no longer true. Indeed, the order of $E[p]$ can be zero or $p$.

Comment: Thank you very much for you clarifications @AriyanJavanpeykar. Could you explain a little more to what extent the order of $E[p]$ is related to the existence of an *étale* cover? I actually do not see, even intuitively, why your discussion about the order (on which I agree) is a "reason" why we have an étale cover.

Comment: Let $n>0$, and consider the "forgetful" morphism of modular curves $Y(3n)\to Y(3)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Recall that the curve $Y(i)$ parametrizes pairs $(E,\phi)$, where $E$ is an elliptic curve and $\phi$ is a level $i$-structure on $E$, i.e., the choice of an isomorphism $\phi:E[i] \cong \mathbb{Z}/i\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/i\mathbb{Z}$. Now, if $Y(3n)\to Y(3)$ would want to be etale, then the cardinality of the fibre over a point  in $Y(3)$ should be independent of that point....

Comment: The fibre over a point $(E,\phi)$ consists of the pairs $(E,phi, \psi)$ with $\psi$ an level $n$-structure on $E$ (and $E$ and $\phi$ fixed). So, how many different level $n$-structures are there on $E$ (forgetting $\phi$ now, as it is irrelevant)?
Well, that's given by the cardinality of the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}/i\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/i\mathbb{Z}$ (respecting the Weil pairing, but let's forget that as well for the sake of this discussion); note that I use that we are in characteristic zero here...

Comment: So, you see that, as we are in characteristic zero, the number of choices of level structure on a given elliptic curve is independent of that elliptic curve, because the order of $E[n]$ is constant. Now, in characteristic $p$, the number of choices of "level $p$-structure" depends on whether $E$ is ordinary or supersingular, and this is why the forgetful map can't be etale.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar That is a fantastic answer, thank you very much! So actually, if I understand your reasoning well, the full level-$N$ moduli problem can *not* be étale on the whole of $\mathbf{(Ell)}$, as the cardinality of the fiber may depend on the point (more precisely, of its characteristic) if we do not insure that the prime $p$ we are interested in is invertible on the whole of the base. Is it right? Also, you may copy paste your comments as an answer if you'd like. I would accept it as such.

Comment: Yes that's right. Probably, in characteristic $p$, adding level structure is finite flat over each Newton stratum, e.g., the ordinary locus. But I'm not really sure whether it is etale, because  the group scheme $E[p^n]$ might be non-reduced. (The same amount of points in each fibre isn't always enough to guarantee etaleness. You also need the points to be actual points, instead of "thickened points".)

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Thank you so much for your clarifications :)